# Angular promise in more controllers

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm defining a factory using promises like:

```
.factory('Test', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http){
     var getData = function () {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         $http.get('url')
              .success(function (res) {
                   deferred.resolve(res);
              });

         return deferred.promise;
     }

     return { getData: getData};
}]);
```

Further in a controller I'm using that factory like:

```
Test.getData().then(function (data) { console.log(data);});
```

All works fine, my question is: if I want to use the same promise in another controller to wait for that ajax before I do something else, I should use the same sintax?

```
Test.getData().then(function (data) { console.log(data);});
```

My problem is that I'm using a node js socket to retreive some data and events. In my promise I'm connecting the socket

```
$rootScope.socket = io_connection
```

and in another controller, on anther page I want to emit an event on that socket but $rootScope.socket gets undefined. Since $rootScope.socket gets defined in that first promise, in my other controller I tried:

```
$rootScope.socket.emit('custom_event', { id: 1 });
```

But is undefined...
I hope my writing makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: maybe you should show the code where you initialize the socket and the controller  where you wanna emit an event. You should create the socket in the run phase. - BTW `$http` returns already a  promise, there is no need to wrap another layer around it.

Comment: I made that promise after an example of how to use promises in angular... I will post the code, thanks

Comment: ?? Then I'd look for better examples or for examples with a proper explanation. It might be just an example, but in this scenario it doesn't make sense :-)

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bxbq8j9z/) here's a part of the code that uses socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your `getData` always returns a promise, instead of holding the actual data, you can hold the promise object instead:

```
.factory('LoggedUserData', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    var waitingPromise = null;

    var getData = function () {
        if(!waitingPromise){
            waitingPromise = $http.get('url');
        }
        return waitingPromise;;
    }
    return { getData: getData };
}])
```

now, irrespective of which controller object gets initaized first, both would recieve the same data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define witch controller is instantiated first.

I don't know if is a good idea to make controllers dependent on each other if they don't have scope inheritance.

Maybe you can create this socket inside a Service and use on both controllers.